# strange behavior cursor jumping over letters

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I hit space it moves the cursor over the code, instead of inserting spaces. How do I get back to normal editing mode in visual code studio?

[image]

Comment: I found it: key 'i'  (like in the vim editor made it change to inserting mode)

Comment: Still wondering how this happened, an answer is appreciated!

Comment: I had a plugin vsvim installed: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JaredParMSFT.VsVim